# How to Select a Polygon beneath another Polygon in QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, polygon, select

We have a series of layers that contain polygons with additional polygons 'underneath' each polygon.

How do we select the polygon **beneath** the existing feature without also selecting the feature **above** it?

[image: Selection Example]

Comment: You can select the features using attributes table.

Comment: Hi @Pierma - Yes that's always possible but this is not an efficient method for our workflow.

Comment: Does the polygon beneath have to be beneath the larger polygon?  It may take some time but you could re-digitise all the smaller polygons.  As they will be the most recent addition to the layer they will sit on top of the larger polygons and can then be selected individually.  Alternatively add the attributes of the larger poly to the smaller and doughnut. Then any styling can be done on both polygons and each can be selected separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the **Identify Features** button and click on a point where multiple polygons are present, you can right-click the attribute of the polygon underneath from the list and select `Toggle feature selection`. The polygon should now be selected:

[image: Toggle selection]

Comment: This is a great, simple way of solving the problem and is exactly what we were looking for. Now if we can just figure some way to hot key it!

Comment: @Silvern - Awesome, glad it helped! I'm not exactly sure how to create a hot key for this, you could consider asking this as [a new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :)

Answer (score 5):

If there are only two polygons you can do it rather easily by selecting first the both polygons with the selection tool and then deselecting the outer polygon.

Two polygons

[image]

Both selected, press Ctrl-button down for deselecting the outer polygon

[image]

Result: only the inner polygon stays selected.

[image]

It would make working easier if the selection color could be configured semi-transparent because now the fill color is hiding the borders of the polygon that is behind. But this method does not work if there can be more that two polygons which are covering each other.

Perhaps you should make a feature request and ask QGIS developers to implement same kind of tool than the Select MultiItems tool in OpenJUMP.

In this example there are three polygons in a pile.

[image]

The Select MultiItems tools shows the list of features which were found below the cursor and user can select with check boxes which features get selected on the map. "Validate" confirms the selection and closes the tool.

[image]