# Moving polygon to edge of boundary using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, features, boundaries, outline

I have a set of polygons that have been drawn using a set of plotted addresses.

All of these polygons fall within a geographical boundary of the local area.

As the boundary is drawn using local geography (i.e. rivers, hills etc.), rather than properties, the results look something like this:

[image: Polygons (multi-coloured) within the boundary (black line)]

To complete the task, there are two steps:

Firstly, **bring the edges of the polygons to the border of the boundary** like so:

[image: Corrected polygon boundaries using MSPaint]

After playing with the 'Reshape Features' tool, the end result is very messy and time consuming. I'm confident that there is no real way to automate this but I was wondering if there was a better tool that I could use to drag the polygon to the boundary line? Something that snaps to the line would be ideal.

The second step would be to **connect the outlines of the polygons to 'fill in' the empty space between them**, like so:

[image: MSPaint masterpiece of the finished result]

This would certainly be a manual process as I would need to contour each polygon along riverbanks etc. for a smooth finished result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach: `buffer`, `intersection`, `split with lines` and manually deleting polygons:

1. `buffer` the polygons that you have:
   [image: unbuffered polygons]
   [image: buffered]
2. `intersect` with the outline:
   [image]
3. `split with lines` based on those pink line boundaries you have:
   [image]
4. select and remove overlapping polygons:

   1. toggle editing
   2. select a polygon that is wrong:

      [image]
   3. delete it
   4. note that some polygons are overlapping and need [some special care](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195388/156742) when selecting. Also setting opacity and proper symbology helps here.
      [image]
5. Done!
   [image]